# Duvida em try-catch & vetor JAVA

Tags: java, array

Tenho a seguinte questão:
2.  Declare  um  vetor  de  quatro  posições  do  tipo  de  dados  inteiro,  o  software  deve permanecer  pedindo  para  o  usuário  digitar  um  valor,  até  que  o  mesmo  digite quatro valores válidos,  os valores  válidos  devem  ser armazenados no vetor.
O meu progresso até agora é esse:

```
try
{
    int [] vetor = new int [4];
    System.out.println("Informe o primeiro valor: ");
    vetor[0]=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Informe o segundo valor: ");
    vetor[1]=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Informe o terceiro valor: ");
    vetor[2]=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Informe o quarto valor: ");
    vetor[3]=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Foram digitados valores válidos.");
}catch(Exception erro)
{
    System.out.println("Valor inválido.");
}
```

Minha dúvida é: como fazer ele ficar solicitando o valor até que seja inserido um valor válido.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o seu try/catch dentro de um loop infinito, e deixa-lo rodando até que um inteiro válido seja digitado:

```
while (true) try {
    System.out.println("Informe o primeiro valor: ");
    vetor[0] = entrada.nextInt();
} catch (Exception erro) {
    System.out.println("Valor inválido.");
    entrada.next(); // para consumir a entrada atual, que não é válida
}
```

Mas como repetir toda essa estrutura para cada índice deixaria o código muito poluído, seria melhor organiza-lo dentro de uma função, para reaproveitar o código nas próximas chamadas:

```
static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vetor = new int[4];
    vetor[0] = lerInteiro("Informe o primeiro valor: ");
    vetor[1] = lerInteiro("Informe o segundo valor: ");
    vetor[2] = lerInteiro("Informe o terceiro valor: ");
    vetor[3] = lerInteiro("Informe o quarto valor: ");
}

private static int lerInteiro(String mensagem) {
    while (true) try {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        return entrada.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception erro) {
        System.out.println("Valor inválido.");
        entrada.next();
    }
}
```